# Need to control 10 Tv's remotely and concurrently by an android phone. possible with wi-fi?

Tags: android, wifi, television

I want to make an app for controlling 10 tvs concurrently, by concurrently i mean: you push the open button and each tv opens. It is the main point.

It can be done with RF tech,and there is so much example though. But, what i'd like to know is if it is possible doing this using wi-fi, assuming the tv is supporting wi-fi of course.  any ideas?

Comment: This will depend on the TVs. How do you expect to interface with them?

Comment: If you manage to find the tv-remote protocol, then yes.

Comment: @Jong, okay i will search it.

Answer (score 1):

Controlling 10 or more TV sets using an app is now possible using what is being called pico broadcasters.

These devices use the recently unregulated broadcasting spectrum called "white space" and require an app running on a local machine which the broadcaster then transmits to HDTV sets. Note there are distance limitations and other easily controlled SNAFUs.

search: pico broadcasting